# AJAX datatype JSON and HTML

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am following a tutorial about ajax and I have made this script, where I get data as JSON and append them into a table:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'insert.php', 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: {data1: name, data2: phone, data3: address},
    dataType: "json", 
    success:function(res){
        //if(data=="success")
        //{
            //alert("Data added");
            //console.log(arr.id);
            $("#trId").before("<tr><td>"+res.emp_name+"</td><td>"+res.ph+"</td><td>"+res.add+"</td></tr>");
        //}
    },
    error:function(res){
        alert("data not added");
    }
```

And here is the PHP code:

```
$insert = "INSERT into employee(emp_name, phone, address) VALUES (:emp_name, :ph, :add)";
$insertStmt = $conn->prepare($insert);
$insertStmt->bindValue(":emp_name", $emp_name);
$insertStmt->bindValue(":ph", $pos);
$insertStmt->bindValue(":add", $address);
$insertStmt->execute();

//echo "success";
$lastid = $conn->lastInsertId();
$res = array('name'=>$emp_name, 'ph'=>$pos, 'add'=>$address, 'id'=>$lastid);
echo json_encode($res);
```

Our instructor asked us to transform this script, from JSON as datatype into HTML, and make the initial changes for it. But I can't figure out what should the PHP code returns now, and how to append the returned values into the table.

Secondly, why some people use HTML as datatype while JSON is better ?

Comment: It's not about being `better` ... use cases can be different

Comment: read the ajax documentation -- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ -- "html": Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM. -- "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `dataType` to html:

```
dataType: "html"
```

And render html on server:

```
$res = array('name'=>$emp_name, 'ph'=>$pos, 'add'=>$address, 'id'=>$lastid);
echo "<tr><td>" . $res['name'] . "</td><td>" . $res['ph'] . "</td><td>" . $res['add'] . "</td></tr>"";
```

So in a `success` callback you will receive `html`:

```
success: function(res) {
    $("#trId").before( res );
}
```

Why use `html` instead of `json` - is an opinion-based or a case-based question.